# How can I get an answer on my quotas change request?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've made several requests to change my persistent SSD storage on Google Compute starting almost a month ago but I've never received any answer from Google. What should I do to obtain that quotas upgrade?

The Google documentation points to Stack for requesting help, therefore I ask my question here.

Comment: I think we saw pretty fast responses from them (few days). How did you submit your request?

Comment: I've used the form linked from the quotas page in the Google Compute web UI. Maybe it's linked to the fact that we benefit from the program Google Compute for Startups (https://cloud.google.com/developers/startups/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quota Increase requests are usually actioned upon within 2-3 days, usually during regular work days. You ought to have received, at least, the confirmation email of your original request. If you didn't, perhaps the entered address was not correct.

Another possibility is that the request came from an address that, at the time, was not entitled to request such an increase, that wasn't the owner.

And there's always the ever-present spam folder, where some notifications always seem to land.

Also, be aware that projects in free trial are not allowed to request quota increases: in order to do that, an upgrade out of the free trial is required.

You can always submit a new Quota Increase request: I'm sure it will be actioned upon on short notice. :-)

Comment: I've now received a mail from Google technical support, it looks like they had a problem and my requests were hidden. Everything should now be solved soon, thanks.